# Stub a method inside other method

Tags: ruby, api, testing, rspec

```
module A
  module B
    class C
       def fun(github) 
          return username
       end
       def gun(github)
          author=fun(github)
          #perfom some operation
          return count
       end
    end
end
```

I want to test gun function, but to get the value of author, it is making a call to function fun.
Now, I do not want to call this function and instead stub it.

To achieve that, I wrote this line in the before do section while testing the function_1, But it's not working.

```
      allow(A::B::C).to receive(:fun).and_return("username")
```

I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are instance methods, not class methods, therefore you need to stub the method on the instance.

The following might work for you:

```
let(:abc) { A:B.C.new }
let(:github) { ... }

before { allow(abc).to receive(:fun).and_return("username") }

it "..." do
  expect(abc.fun(github)).to eq(...)
  expect(abc).to have_received(:fun).with(github)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, Does not work

Comment: Can you elaborate? What doesn’t work? Is there an error message?